# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'supabase' after having pip installed

Tags: python, supabase, supabase-py

I'm getting a:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'supabase'

error despite having `pip install supabase`.
Also tried with supabase-py but didn't change anything
Using venv and bot packages appear when running `pip -list`.

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

```
from supabase import create_client, Client
url: str = os.environ.get("SUPABASE_URL")
key: str = os.environ.get("SUPABASE_KEY")
supabase: Client = create_client(url, key)
```

I tried reinstalling the packages and using on a conda environment.

Comment: Probably the wrong pip executable. Try again with `python -m pip install supabase`. Though it should work if you're properly in a virtual-env.

Comment: Don't use a Conda env to solve this, if you're already trying a v-env. That's going to get messy. If you are using Conda, use Conda to install the package.

Comment: What was your installation command?

Comment: If you have python2 and python3 installed, depending on which interpreter is running, you will need to use the pip script associated with each one. If using python2, check if a pip2 script exists, otherwise pip3. You can check if your module is installed right after installing it by running python and manually typing `import supabase`. Also, it looks like your import statement has a comma after it. Imports should be one per line. EDIT: supabase is python3 only, so make sure your interpreter is >=3.8